Architecture of a scientific software
First things first, I was not sure it was the right place to seek advice and feedback about software architecture, but this post on meta.stackexchange conviced me to do so. I hope my question finds an echo here.
TL;DR
I'm thinking about a technical stack and an architecture to quickly develop an easy-to-access, collaborative software capable of displaying scientific data that can be very large (several gigabytes) in 2D and 3D. I'm keen to hear your advice and feedback on my reasoning.
More context
I'm about to start developing a scientific application. I'm currently thinking about the architecture and the technical stack. To describe the application (very) simply: it will have to manage projects containing scientific data. In each project, the user will be able to load and display scientific data. I can elaborate further if needed.
The project is not complex if only some of the needs are addressed. But addressing all the needs and constraints that I have is a bit challenging.
Here are some user requirements relevant/structuring for the software architecture:

Easy deployment and simplified access to the software.
Collaborative: at least be able to share projects so that other users can display data available in shared projects.
Simple to use. Without compromising the user experience.
2D and 3D visualisation of scientific data.
Data confidentiality: some data is confidential and users must ensure that they retain ownership and confidentiality of their data.

Here are the structuring technical needs and issues that I have identified. Some stem directly from user needs:

The presentation layer must enable the creation of a user-friendly UI/UX.
Reuse of existing code (much of it open source), mainly written in Python.
Perfomance: some of the data is very large (around ten gigabytes).

Finally, a major constraint: we have to develop an MVP in 1 year with a team of 3 developers.
Nature of the data
The data in question is geoscientific data of various kinds: maps and images of the surface, 3D models, surfaces, point clouds, LiDAR, physical measurements that change over time.
The size of the data can vary from a few KB to several GB. Some are binary, others ASCII. Reading this data is relatively simple using existing Python packages.
Possible solutions
So far I'm considering 2 very different solutions, but none of them fully satisfies me. Here are simplified descriptions.
Solution 1
A simple stack that would meet some of the requirements, but would overlook accessibility and collaboration: a thick client in Python with:

UI using Qt(Python)
3D visualisation using VTK(Python)
2D visualisation mainly using matplotlib(Python) and friends
Business logic can be developed simply in Python
This stack means you can quickly develop an MVP and naturally reuse all the available Python code. On the UI/UX side, I won't have the flexibility and beauty of web technologies, but it could be enough. The application can be packaged with PyInstaller or equivalent. The application runs on the end-user's machine, alongside the data. No data confidentiality issues.

Solution 2
A more complex stack to take account of all requirements, but one that requires much greater effort and complicates development. A client/server application with:

On Client side:

UI using web technologies, with a JS framework such as React/Vue/Angular
3D visualisation using VTKjs (rendering is done on the server side for performance reasons)
2D visualisation seems more complex to me with this stack. Perhaps a project like https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3 could help. JS ecosystem offers various packages to draw fancy charts and maps, but I need to reuse existing Python code.


On Server side:

A web server in Python with FastAPI or Django
3D rendering using VTK(Python). Communicates with VTKjs via websocket
Business logic can be developed in Python
Development is much more complicated. The data must be sent to the server before use, which means that 2D/3D rendering must be done as much as possible on the server side, for performance reasons. The server is developed in Python to allow the use of existing business logic and code. The application is deployed on our own premises or on the customer's premises in a private or public cloud. The cybersecurity aspects will be very important with this solution. If user data leaks out, it's a disaster!



Discussions
Ideally, I would have preferred to go for solution 1. I'm not a fan of introducing complexity too early, before it's necessary. My philosophy is rather to anticipate the evolution of the software and add complexity when it's needed. With solution 1, I can isolate the business logic in Python libraries, so that it can be reused in a server if one day the application needs to evolve into a client/server application (close to solution 2). The major problem with this solution is that it's much less accessible than a web application, and the collaborative aspect is very complicated to implement (so I might not implement it, in the end).
I also considered using WASM to combine web and Python technologies (with Pyodide) in a client-side application, to simplify development by avoiding the client/server aspect as much as possible. But the limitations (of Pyiodide, and the amount of memory available in the browser) and the fact that the collaborative aspect is not resolved by this solution mean that I don't think it's a good idea.
It's a bit of a long post, but at the same time it's very short. I've tried to include just the essentials to help you think things through. Any though, any comment, any suggestion, any idea is much appreciated.
Thank you for reading to the end!

Access over internet is a major requirement in modern society. Other requirements are often secondary. If you agree then you have to go for the web application. Simple as that. The rest are implementation details. As long as you follow general rules (layers of abstraction, separation of concerns) then don't overthink it. It shouldn't be hard to refactor it if needed.

Thanks for the comment. I agree, but I'm still not 100% confident. What bothers me the most are the unknowns related to data and performance. In my field there is no existing web application (at least I don't know any) and I think the main reason is confidentiality and regulation of data, and performance. Basically, your data has to be stored on your intranet or on your laptop. And since the data is often large, the application has to be smart enough to handle large data sets on the server-side and render what is needed on the client-side. Indeed it's much simpler with a desktop application.

Well, it is unlikely you are going to transfer gigabytes of data over the network, right? You would rather process it and aggregate and send only final compact summary to the client. In such situation it is easier to control performance on your own machines rather than on clients. Confidentiality is of course problematic. But since you want to share data then client side confidentiality is close to impossible. On the server side you can implement anonymization or even custom encryption. But on client side it doesn't mean anything. Yes, it is hard. But I don't think this difficulty is avoidable

Indeed, we never send the whole data over the network. Usually we decimate/compress/tile and so forth, even for (advanced) desktop applications. Anonymisation and encryption is a good point, I will look into it, see what's available. Anyway, thanks for your contribution!

In my opinion a critical flaw with your plan is an overly broad scope, in that you do not define what "scientific data" is. There are just a huge number of different types of data, and many ways to store that data. If you plan to handle all kinds of data there is just no way it will be simple to use. I have spent a fair bit of time trying to get excel to plot data the way I want, and that is probably the most trivial case possible.
Some few examples I have had experience with, mostly centered around imaging:

Medical imaging usually use dicom files. This is a very large and complex format, to the point that each vendor needs to supply "DICOM conformance statement".
Thermal imaging often use vendor specific formats, since the format may contain calibration data and proprietary algorithms for computing the temperature from the cameras sensor values.
Any 16 bit image format will likely require processing to get decent contrast. The type of processing will depend on the type of data. Perhaps a simple linear transform is sufficient? Maybe some form of histogram equalization is needed? Maybe some spatial filtering to remove or enhance specific frequencies?
Image data is often compressed, but the type of compression often varies. Jpeg2k? JpegLs?, png? deflate? Some proprietary algorithm?

Existing software like Matlab and VTK let the user handle the most of the complex task of reading and transforming the data into a representation that is suitable for visualization.
So you will need to balance easy of use with flexibility. If you want to prioritize simplicity you likely want to narrow your scope significantly. If you want to prioritize flexibility you will likely end up with some kind of programming API. It is also possible to provide a layered model, where the user can chose the level of flexibility/easy of use for their particular problem.

Thank you for your reply, which has enabled me to clarify my question. I'm going to add information about the nature of the data to my question. And apart from the question of data, the scope is broad anyway and I have to deal with it :) You mentioned Matlab and VTK (Paraview), which are often used by our users, as well as QGIS or ArcGIS. But they are too advanced and complicated. Our aim is to simplify these functions and provide only the relevant elements.

@NicolasC. I suspect you will find that each scientist have different views about what is "relevant" or not. One of the big advantages of Matlab are the various toolboxes that provide specialized tools for a specific domain, often written by scientists in that field. If you want to target as broad a  customer base as Matlab you likely need to do something similar.
